# Time Range to Offset Capital Losses Against Capital Gains

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, shares, capital-loss

I am trying to better understand how long after a capital gains loss, you can offset value against a capital tax gain. The Government website states;

> When you report a loss, the amount is deducted from the gains you made
>   in the same tax year.
>
> If your total taxable gain is still above the tax-free allowance, you
>   can deduct unused losses from previous tax years. If they reduce your
>   gain to the tax-free allowance, you can carry forward the remaining
>   losses to a future tax year.
>   You do not have to report losses straight away - you can claim up to 4
>   years after the end of the tax year that you disposed of the asset.

does this mean one of the two scenarios below is correct?;

**Scenario 1:**
You must claim your losses within 4 years of them occurring and, you must also use the losses within that time. If any gains are made after those 4 years then, these losses cannot be used to offset the tax.

**Scenario 2:**
You must claim your losses within 4 years of them occurring but, once they have been claimed you can then use them at any point in the future to offset tax for any gains?

Comment: My guess is scenario 1.

Comment: You must declare the loss within 4 years, however, once declared they can be carried forward indefinitely.  Simply include a note each year with your return stating that you are carrying forward X-amount of losses from the previous year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can carry losses forward indefinitely. Or, at least, until they change the tax law again:

> The 20-year carryforward period has been replaced with an indefinite carryforward period

https://www.bpcpa.com/newsletters/business-and-net-operating-losses-changes-for-2018/

Comment: That link applies to US not UK.